# swift how to convert Decimal type to String type

Tags: swift, decimal

How to convert `Decimal` to `String` in swift?

For example

```
let de = Decimal(string: "123")
```

then how to convert `de` to String.

Comment: `de.description` but you might need to use `as NSDecimalNumber` to access `description(withLocale:)`. You might also use `NumberFormatter` although it always converts decimals to `double` first but that is not a problem in most cases.

Comment: decimal to string or string to decimal

Comment: Unfortunately you can't have both localisation AND exact decimals supported when converting from Decimal to String. See https://openradar.appspot.com/29923468

Answer (score 18):

Leveraging the fact that Decimal conforms to protocol `CustomStringConvertible` I would simply do:

```
let decimalString = "\(de)"
```

Comment: String interpolation works, but I prefer using `String(describing: de)` as it is [what Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible) to use when manipulating types conforming to CustomStringConvertible: "The `String(describing:)` initializer is the preferred way to convert an instance of _any_ type to a string."

Comment: No, this is wrong! CustomStringConvertible is a debugging API and you shouldn't use it for serialization.

Comment: Hi @IsaaсWeisberg where have you seen that `CustomStringConvertible` is a debugging API?

Comment: Maybe @IsaaсWeisberg you meant this other protocol? [CustomDebugStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customdebugstringconvertible)

Answer (score 9):

Convert to NSDecimalNumber and use the stringValue.

`NSDecimalNumber(decimal: de).stringValue`

Comment: That seems like a very inefficient way to do this. `String(describing: de)` seems to be a better approach, or using String interpolation like @Marco answered

Comment: This is the correct way because String(describing:) is a debugging API

Answer (score -3):

Use an `NSNumberFormatter` to parse your input. Set its `generatesDecimalNumbers` property to true:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
```

Here's how you use it, if you want to return 0 when the string can't be parsed:

```
func decimal(with string: String) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    return formatter.number(from: string) as? NSDecimalNumber ?? 0
}

decimal(with: "80.00")

// Result: 80 as an NSDecimalNumber
```

By default, the formatter will look at the device's locale setting to determine the decimal marker. You should leave it that way. For the sake of example, I'll force it to a French locale:

```
// DON'T DO THIS. Just an example of behavior in a French locale.
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr-FR")

decimal(with: "80,00")
// Result: 80

decimal(with: "80.00")
// Result: 0
```

If you really want to always use a comma as the decimal mark, you can set the `decimalSeparator` property:

```
formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
```

Comment: NumberFormatter internally uses double precision, not decimal precision. EVEN when generateDecimalNumbers is set to true.

Comment: The question asks how to convert a `Decimal` to a `String`, not how to convert a `String` to a `Decimal`. For the former case, you wouldn't need to set `formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers` to `true` and you'd call `formatter.string(from: number)`, not `formatter.number(from: string)`. However, @Berik [claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610567/swift-how-to-convert-decimal-type-to-string-type#comment96983929_52001734) that wouldn't work exactly for every possible `Decimal` value.

Comment: I must have misread the question.

Answer (score -3):

In Swift 3 and above try this

```
extension Formatter {
    static let stringFormatters: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .none
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension Decimal {
    var formattedString: String {
        return Formatter.stringFormatters.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

you can show like this

```
label.text = someDecimal.formattedString
```

Comment: NumberFormatter internally uses double precision. This extension would not return valid Decimal representations.

Comment: I think it's `string(from:)`, not `string(for:)`.